# An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: TypeError Message: Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller code

```
 public function edit($increment_name) {
        $this->load->model("RequestModel");
     
        $request_data['request'] = $this->RequestModel->editRequest($increment_name);
        
        // Debug the contents of $request_data['request']
        //var_dump($request_data);
        $this->load->view('components/layout');
        $this->load->view('client/edit', $request_data);
       
       
    }
```

Model code

```
 public function editRequest($increment_name) {
        $request_query = $this->db->get_where('tblrequest', ['increment_name' => $increment_name]);
    
        $request_data = $request_query->row_array();
        return $request_data;
    }
```

view code

```
<?php foreach ($request as $item): ?>
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <input type="text" class="inputstylenum" name="item_name[]" value="<?= $item['item_name'] ?>" placeholder="Item name" required>
                <input type="number" name="stock_quantity[]" value="<?= $request['stock_quantity']; ?>>" class="inputstylenum" required>
                <input type="number" name="available_quantity[]" value="<?php echo $item['available_quantity']; ?>" class="inputstylenum" required>
                <button type="button" class="remove-btn btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want to show the data there are multiple products with the same increment_name. I want to show all items using this loop. am using the CodeIgniter framework.

Comment: In the view, `$request['stock_quantity']` probably should be `$item['stock_quantity']`

Comment: Still the same error is coming, i add the //var_dump($request_data); to check whether all the data is comming or not. all data is coming but not showing in the view

Comment: @kavishkachamuditha Should you not be iterating over `$request_data` instead of `$request` in your view?

Comment: I tried that also but coming as Undefined variable. i have fields such as first_name, last_name that data are coming when use $request  <input type="text" class="form-control frmwidth" name="first_name" value="<?= $request['first_name'] ?>" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter the person first name" required>

Comment: In the model, `$request_data = $request_query->row_array();` should probably be `$request_data = $request_query->result_array();`. Right now you're only returning the first row of the result set.

Comment: ^ if query returns "false" it is not an array but a string, you need to add this exception to your code, to cover situations, when there is no result returned...